# Array GET all data and add page number at end

Tags: php, arrays, get, httpbuilder

I have the following code. I want the code to get all of the data from the current url which is like

```
search.php?q=dvd+player&attr=23903940_portable_dvd_player&attr=23903945_cd&attr=23903935_mpeg_4
```

Code:

```
<?php if ($pagecount > 1)
    { 
        $paramsP1 = array_merge($_GET, array("page" => $pagecount-1));
        $new_page_1 = http_build_query($paramsP1);
    ?>

<li><a href="search.php?<?php echo $new_page_1; ?>"><b>&laquo; Previous</b></a></li>

    <?php } ?>
```

The code for some reason only obtains one of the GET variables which always seems to be the last one, so in this case its attr=23903935_mpeg_4 and adds "&page=X" onto it.

I have been looking at this code for a while however cant seem to understand why only one variable is returned.

Comment: Do a `var_dump` of your `$_GET` var before you merge your "page array" with it. And let us know the result.

Comment: If your query variables have the same name (here it is "attr") the last one overrides the ones before.

Comment: Could you post the `var_dump` as requested by @TiMESPLiNTER?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of merging your get array with a new array, you could simply use the query string and append to it, like so:

```
$new_url = 'search.php?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] . '&page=' . ($pagecount-1);
```

Comment: Hi, I tried something similar to this however the only issue is that if say the user is on page 4 already and they wish to go on page 3 then "&page=4" will be on the url. search.php?search.php?q=dvd+player&attr=23903940_portable_dvd_player&attr=price_range_20_184&page=5&page=4

Answer (score 0):

Use [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function. But you have a incorect url because of same variables name.

```
   $url = 'search.php?q=dvd+player&attr=23903940_portable_dvd_player&attr=23903945_cd&attr=23903935_mpeg_4';
    parse_str($url, $output);
    var_dump($output);
```